# JS: setInterval has weird behavior with chrome throttling

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, setinterval, throttling

I was testing my website out with chrome throttling, using the low-end mobile. I noticed one of my JS intervals were running much slower than it should be for no reason. I decided to investigate further, so I wrote this code:

```
let prev = Date.now();
let x = 0;
setInterval(() => {
  if(x++ % 100 == 0) {
    console.log(Date.now() - prev);
    prev = Date.now();
  }
}, 10);
```

It sets an interval to run every 10ms, and it prints the time elapsed every 100 runs. This should be 1 second, but it is printing 4-8 seconds. This shouldn't happen, because getting the date every 100 runs, and then logging it, should be a piece of cake, even for "low-end mobile".

My best guess right now is that chrome's throttling also specifically throttles the event loop, which sometimes gives misleading results, like here. Is this true?

Comment: Modern Chrome throttles timers in inactive/backgrounded tabs.

Comment: This is explained in the docs for [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout#reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified), the same can be applied to the intervals.

Comment: @Teemu where in the docs? I don't see the relevant section

Comment: Teemu was referring to this paragraph: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout#timeouts_in_inactive_tabs However this is assuming that you indeed had your tab in the background. FWIW, I can't reproduce otherwise with my Chrome 99 on macOs

Comment: My tab isn't in the background